# What is the recommended way to clean my system after removing an rpm?

Tags: package-management, rpm

Assume I remove an rpm as follows:

```
rpm -e <package-name>
```

I then do a system wide search:

```
find / |grep <keyword-from-package-name>
```

It returns many instances where the keyword was referenced e.g.

```
/etc/<keyword-from-package-name>
```

If I do the following:

```
ll /etc/<keyword-from-package-name>
```

I get the following response:

```
total 0
```

Which means the directory is empty, so in the interest of keeping a system tidy:

My question is, what is the recommended way of removing leftover files and directories after removing rpm?

Is it by finding each individual instance and verifying that the file/directory is empty, as described above, and then doing an;

```
rm -f filename.extension
```

OR

```
rm -rf directory_name
```

What do you do?

Thank you

Comment: What's the problem with leaving an empty directory lying around? In other words, is solving the problem not a waste of resources?

Comment: @wurtel Thanks for your response. This may very well be the correct answer, i'm just starting out in my career and was wondering what the more experienced Unix users do. I suppose I assumed that leaving empty directories lying around was/is bad practice. From your answer I assume that an empty directory takes up no system resources, save for some links to the directory name/nodes on the file system tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is that the package was not perfectly packaged (as many packages are... sadly): The package installed the `/etc/<package>` directory but did not **own** it; so it was not removed upon uninstall. Normally you are not supposed to do any extra actions after removing an rpm.

probably the owner had something like this in his spec file:

```
%files
/etc/<package>/*
```

which should have been:

```
%files
/etc/<package>/
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, I will look into this I interpret what your saying as: Whoever created the spec file etc... did not include "commands" to ensure the package OWNED each directory it created, therefore when I did rpm - e  <package-name> these directories could not be removed as the correct ownership privileges were not present. I plan on investigating the creation of rpms soon, I will definitely keep this in mind when creating them .Thank you

Comment: @MarkMark : I added the concerned spec file parts in my answer

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I did not write the spec file but I do have access it. This is what it contains:  %files -f %{EXTRA_FILES} %defattr(-,root,root). EXTRA_FILES is defined at the start of the spec file and when I follow the path it links to I see you are correct as it is a file that contains paths like for example /etc/<package>/*

Comment: Well that means that in extra_files they forgot to add the dir /etc/<package>

Comment: Correct (see above your last comment)